# Setting focus on table row elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a table list of items that I want to be able to scroll through using the keyboard up and down buttons. I am currently able to get the similar desired effect of moving down the list with the tabindex attribute. I am also using ng repeat to generate the instances of the  elements. Tips or clues on how to achieve being able to focus and scroll up and down the list by using the up and down keys?

Sample code below.

```
table ng-if="!toolbarCtrl.loadingContacts" class="table dataTable hover" id="table3">
                <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
                    <tr class="pointer" tabindex="0" ng-repeat="contact in toolbarCtrl.contactEntities | filter:toolbarCtrl.toolbarSearchStringAfterDelay | orderBy: toolbarCtrl.tab == toolbarCtrl.tabs.RECENT ? '-dateSeen' : (toolbarCtrl.tab == toolbarCtrl.tabs.ALL ? '+data.fileAs' : '')"
                        ng-class="" ng-if="toolbarCtrl.toolbarSearchStringAfterDelay" ng-click="toolbarCtrl.selectContact(contact)"> 
                        <td rel="popover_dark" ng-class="contact.loading ? 'contactDisabled' : '' " data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="" class="sorting_1 has_popover">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I mutated your checkKey function to become this

```
 controller.checkKey = function (event) {
        $("tr[tabindex=0]").focus();
        var event = window.event;
        if (event.keyCode == 40) { //down
            var idx = $("tr:focus").attr("tabindex");
            idx++;
            if (idx > 6) {
                idx = 0;
            }
            $("tr[tabindex=" + idx + "]").focus();
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38) { //up
            var idx = $("tr:focus").attr("tabindex");
            idx--;
            if (idx < 0) {
                idx = 6;
            }
            $("tr[tabindex=" + idx + "]").focus();
        }
    }
```

I'm close but its skipping straight to the last element. Does this look right?

Comment: I can see why you're getting all tabindex="0" too...you're not using a variable for the tabindex value, you're assigning it to 0 every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little technique for handling the keydown events for up/down arrows to navigate your table rows (`<tr>`). You may need to tweak the upper and lower tabindex handling from your generated data but that's on you. GL!

(jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkna8jgu/2/ )

Sample HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr tabindex="0">
    <td>first row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="1">
    <td>second row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="2">
    <td>third row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="3">
    <td>fourth row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="4">
    <td>fifth row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="5">
    <td>sixth row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr tabindex="6">
    <td>seventh row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr[tabindex=0]").focus();    
    document.onkeydown = checkKey;
});

function checkKey(e) {
    var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
    if(event.keyCode == 40){ //down
      var idx = $("tr:focus").attr("tabindex");
      idx++;
      if(idx > 6){
        idx = 0;
      }
      $("tr[tabindex="+idx+"]").focus();
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38){ //up
      var idx = $("tr:focus").attr("tabindex");
      idx--;
      if(idx < 0){
        idx = 6;
      }
      $("tr[tabindex="+idx+"]").focus();      
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm close to having it right however the different <tr>'s are generated with angular hence they all have a tabindex=0. I understand this should have them navigable in visually logical order. Currently the down and up keys focus the instance of <tr> that is at the bottom of the list.

Comment: I see. Shy of getting angular to stop that, you could use jQuery `$("tr[tabindex=0]").each` to fix the tabindex values for your `<tr>`'s if that is an option for you.

Comment: my only level  of confusion is with the     `$("tr[tabindex=0]").each(function(idx){        
           $(this).attr("tabindex",idx);
    });` Does this set each item in the array to have the value of their tabindex to be = idx?

Comment: That's correct. In my opinion, you should be handling the tabindex values in your angular code that builds the table instead of assigning zero to every row, however if this is not flexible, the code i've offered today will reindex the tabindex values by using the jquery loop (`each`). that code gets all `<tr tabindex="0">` elements, loops through and reassigns the tabindex attribute value to the index value in the loop. This produce correctly incremented tabindex values so the remaining up/down navigation works properly.

Comment: What I understand is your approach renumbers the tabindex to be i++ increments thus I would not need to set the tab index attribute to 0 in the onset.

Comment: You need to set the `tabindex="0"` or else the jQuery selector will not work to re-index them. If you want to remove the `tabindex="0"`, change the jQuery selector to `$("tr.pointer")` and it will work fine like this https://jsfiddle.net/qkna8jgu/4/

Answer (score 0):

This was the approach that I used. It operates the jquery focus on a custom id that is created using the name and angular index. The preventDefault is merely because the up and down keys were also shifting my page up and down, this gets rid of that.

```
controller.checkKey = function (event, index) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.keyCode === 40) {
            $('#item-' + (++index)).focus();
        }
        if (event.keyCode === 38) {
            $('#item-' + (--index)).focus();
        }
    };
```

This approach works well for angular paradigm and the jquery examples above are great too.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way without using the indexes. You can merely use nextElementSibling and previousElementSibling. This example is adopted for selecting the table header instead. I'm just using plain ole JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th tabindex="0">Col 1</th>
        <th tabindex="1">Col 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>first row</td>
        <td>first row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>second row</td>
        <td>first row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>third row</td>
        <td>first row</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
const d = document;
d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

d.querySelector("th[tabindex='0']").focus();
  
d.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    const t = event.target;
    const k = event.keyCode;
    if (k === 40) { //right
        const next = t.nextElementSibling;
        if (next) { next.focus(); }
    } else if (k === 38) { //left 
        const prev = t.previousElementSibling;
        if (prev) { prev.focus(); }
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```